# Second monitor is laggy in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and a [BenQ EW2440L](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00HVCJS8K?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_search_detailpage) as a second monitor.

The problem that I encounter is the fact that the second screen is really laggy, rendering it barely usable.

I have tried Compiz, as well as setting it manually with `xrandr` like so:

```
xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 50
```

but I get `Size 1920x1080 not found in available modes`.

This is the output when running `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-1 connected
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 531mm x 298mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576i      50.1  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
   832x624        74.6
```

My graphics card is certainly on, as running `glxinfo | grep rendering` yields `direct rendering: Yes`.

Nothing that I have found online helped, so I'm either really close, but doing something wrong, either I have an entirely different problem.

Comment: Which output on teh card are you using?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then the answer is `1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  `